# chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255 inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, pytest

Below is my Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.17

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache chromium chromium-chromedriver wget curl unzip gnupg
RUN pip install selenium
ENV DISPLAY=:99
CMD Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16 -nolisten tcp

RUN mkdir /pytest-container/
COPY ./ /pytest-container/
ADD .. /pytest-container/
WORKDIR /pytest-container/

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .pynacl_deps build-base python3-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install -r requirements.txt \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY .. .

CMD ["pytest"]
```

Below is the implementation in conftest:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
#def setup(request, browser=None):
def setup(request):
    global driver
    browser = os.getenv('BROWSER')
    service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("window-size=1024,768")
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    options.add_argument("--silent")
    options.add_argument("--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp")
    # options.binary_location = f"/opt/headless-chromium"
    options.binary_location = "/usr/lib/chromium/chrome"
    chrome_driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
    if browser == "chrome":
         driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    elif browser == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
    elif browser == "edge":
        driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("www.example.com")
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default=os.environ.get('BROWSER', 'chrome'),
                     help="specify the browser to use for running the tests (chrome, firefox, or edge)")



@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")
```

for now, I am just trying to configure chrome out of my browser options. I am facing "chromedriver unexpectedly exited with error code 255" issue while running the tests in docker on a MacBook with M1 chip, I am able to build the image successfully. I have tried every solution suggested on stackoverflow and banging my head from days. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I tried installing different versions of chromedriver, but nothing worked.